# How to build Cakephp3 ORM query for IF.. ELSE?

Tags: php, sql, cakephp-3.0

I am new to the ORM concept. Please build the below query to Cakphp3 ORM format.

```
select sum(case when tr_type = 'credit' then awards else -awards end) as balance 
from user_orders where user_id = 12345;
```

Comment: You should have at least tried something, anything, to solve this problem. This is just a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
    $query = $this->UserOrders->find()->where(['user_id' => 12345]);

             $awards = $query->newExpr()
                            ->addCase(
                                [
                                    $query->newExpr()->add(['tr_type' => 'credit'])
                                ],
                                [
                                    $query->newExpr()->add(['awards' => '-awards'])
                                ]);

$query->select(['balance' => $query->func()->sum($awards)]);
```

more info: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions

You can see the Class File QueryExpresions.php, the methods comments has too many examples.